# mod_rewrite behaving strangely

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to show example.com/c/bla
as example.com/bla
it is working properly when i write 
example.com/bla inside url bar but when i click some link(example.com/bla) from example.com,it redirects to example.com/c/bla

my htaccess code is this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options -Indexes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/c/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /c/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is `/bla` a directory?

Comment: yes
and i also have index.php in bla which contains
include"../index.php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to trailing slash being added by `mod_dir` module after this rewrite rule. Have it this way:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
DirectorySlash Off
Options -Indexes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /home/

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/home/c/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!c/).*)$ c/$1 [L,NC]
```

Test this in a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: Got it,yes it is because of slashes.
but above code not working -_-

Comment: Not working has no information about the error. What error do you get? Did you clear browser cache?

Comment: Test in chrome dev tool and see if there is any redirect showing in Net tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72264/discussion-between-amit-saharan-and-anubhava).